# div bigger than body tag

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a little project and I am making an admin panel. I have a tiny problem with my markup. I am trying to divide my page into 2 columns: left - admin panel, right contains navigation bar and content itself. The problem is that my content is expanding too much and becomes bigger than the html tag and that's causing my 2 columns to be uneven height. How can I fix it?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
{{ stylesheet_link ('css/admin.css')}}
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="admin-panel">
        <h4>Navigation</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="" class="active-item">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Email</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Pages</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Tables</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="admin-navbar">
            <ul>
                <?= Tag::form(array('admin/search','method'=>
                'GET')) ;?>
                <?= Tag::textField(array('search', 'maxlength'=>
                '30'));?>
                <?= Tag::submitButton('Search');?>
                <?= Tag::endForm(); ?>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-item">Profile</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">My Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Account Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/" class="navbar-item">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h2 id="dashboard" class="header">Dashboard</h2>
            {{ content()}}
            <h2 id="email">Email</h2>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css:

**EDITED:**

```
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
body {
background: #eee;
}
.container {
position: relative;
}
.admin-panel, .wrapper {
float:left;
height:100%;
}

.wrapper {
margin:0;
width:1100px;
height:auto;
float:left;
}

.admin-navbar {
background: #222;
height:50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
-mozilla-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
border-bottom:2px solid #000;
}
.admin-navbar ul {
height:50px;
line-height: 50px;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
} 
ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.admin-navbar ul li {
float:right;
}
.admin-navbar>ul>li>a {
display: block;
text-align: center;
color:#fff;
padding:0 5px;
width:140px;

}
.admin-navbar ul li a:hover {
background:#282828;
}

.admin-navbar ul li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top:50px;
padding:5px;
background: #333;
width:140px;
right:0;
height: auto;
}
.admin-navbar ul li ul li {
margin:0;
padding:0;
display: block;
float:left;
width:100%;
}
.admin-navbar ul li ul li a{
display: block;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 30px;
border-radius: 2px;
}
.admin-navbar ul li ul li a:hover{
background: #228856;
}
.admin-navbar ul li:hover ul { 
display: block;
}

.admin-navbar form {
display: inline-block;
}
.admin-navbar form input {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:30px;
}
.admin-navbar form input[type="text"] {
border:none;
width:200px;
}
.admin-navbar form input[type="submit"] {
background:#fff;
border:none;
width:70px;
color:#000;
}
.admin-navbar form input[type="submit"]:hover {
background: #285;
color:#fff;
cursor: pointer;
}
.admin-panel {
background: #222;
width:219px;
padding:20px 15px;
margin:0;
height:100%;
float:left;
}
.admin-panel h4 {
padding:0;
margin:0;
color:#fff;
}
.admin-panel ul {
margin:0;
margin-top:30px;
padding:0;
}
.admin-panel ul li {
display: block;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom:5px;
border-radius:5px;
}
.admin-panel ul li a {
display: block;
padding-top:10px;
line-height: 15px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-bottom:10px;
background: #333;
border-radius: 5px;
height:15px;
}
.admin-panel ul li a:hover {
background: #fff;
color:#111;
}
ul li a.active-item {
background: #285;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.content {
padding:10px;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}
.header {
background: #fff;
}
a {
color:#fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
padding:0;
margin:0;
text-align: center;
}
h2 {
color:#111;
}

table {

padding:0;
border-spacing: 0;
background: #fff;
width:100%;
}
table tr {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background: #333;

}
table tr td {
color:#fff;
}
table tr a {
color:#fff;
display: inline-block;
}
table tr a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
table tr td, table tr th {
border:1px solid #1d2939;
text-align: center;
}
table tr:hover {
background: #285;
}
table tr th {
background:#418bca;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALL YOU NEED: for a good start

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/desid/4/edit)**

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}    /* Ugly reset */
html, body {
  height:100%;
  background: #555;        /* to fulfill page background */
}

/*admin*/

.admin-panel {
  position:absolute;       /* to make it height 100% */
  height:100%;
  width:219px;
  background: #222;
}
.admin-content{  /* added in order to add inner paddings */
  padding:20px 15px;
}

/*page*/

.wrapper {
  margin-left:219px;       /* admin width */
 }

.admin-navbar, .content{
  padding:20px 15px;
}
```

So all you need are 2 main containers, the ADMIN panel on the left and WRAPPER on the right.
Don't use floats or you'll mess it all up, set a width for ADMIN, and leave the browser decide for WRAPPER. Move WRAPPER to the ADMIN's right using `margin-left`.

Regarding the paddings, if you set paddings to i.e. ADMIN, you'll overflow the BODY height, so we need to use for both some inner containers to whom we'll apply the desired padding spaces.